# html/javascript editor that shows result as you type 

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a html/javascript editor that shows the result in a side pane instantly without having to save the code, alt+tab and refresh . Don't need any other features. 
Just learning javascript and it would be great if there was something that would show instantly the result of the code.

This is the final autohotkey script , which saves , switches to firefox , swithes to the first tab and reloads.:

```
F9::
Send ^s
Sleep, 100
if WinExist("ahk_class  MozillaWindowClass")
  {
  WinActivate
  ControlFocus, MozillaWindowClass
  }
Sleep, 200
Send ^1
Send {F5}
return
```

Comment: If it showed results while you typed, wouldn't that result in a lot of errors since it would be displaying incomplete code? I'd suggest jsfiddle though.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Then something that would require only one key press (save/and reload) , and won't take the focus away from the editor?

Comment: What about Tinkerbin? http://tinkerbin.com/

Comment: I ended up setting a autohotkey script to save file, switch to firefox and reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ It's an online editor and works rather well for what it sounds like you're trying to do. It comes with some common libraries built in and it's easy to just start up and begin working. When I first started learning javascript I found it incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Tinkerbin - http://tinkerbin.com/. It can auto update and save your work for later too.

Answer (score 0):

w3schools.com has tryit asp pages to  practice while learning. I found this very helpful as a beginner when started with javascript. JSfiddle is another option.